# Running AppleScript inside of Python script

Tags: python, macos, accessibility

I'm trying to run the AppleScript inside of my Python script but it does not work. When I run the same AppleScript in the AppleScriptEditor it works perfectly!

This is my code:

```
script = '''
            tell application "System Events"
                set position of first window of application process "%(app)s" to {100, 100}
            end tell
            ''' % {'app': app}

        print(script)

        p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate(script)
```

I'm printing the script and eveything is correct

```
tell application "System Events"
                set position of first window of application process "Terminal" to {100, 100}
            end tell
```

but I do not know why it does not move the Terminal window. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Most  likely the Python process is not allowed to touch the window. Manipulating Windows of other processes is a privileged operation that require your app to be whitelisted. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291574/osascript-is-not-allowed-assistive-access-1728

To see if this is the case, inspect the stderr value returned from Popen and see if it contains something like “ osascript is not allowed assistive access”.

Edit: In Mojave, Apple Events are now sandboxes and will have to be approved by the user. https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/06/28/apple-event-sandboxing-in-macos-mojave-lacks-essential-apis/

Comment: What did stdout/stderr contain?

Comment: How can I check it? I run my script in terminal and do not get anything there

Comment: By printing the variables?

Comment: `Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)`

Comment: Are you by any chance using the Mojave beta? https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/06/apple-event-sandboxing-in-macos-mojave

Comment: `Terminal` is not the application trying to send the events.

Comment: See the link in my previous comment. Mojave tightened security and there is no way to do what you want without user interaction (and seemingly hardly even then).